# Having issues zooming with d3.js scaleBand when I use rescaleX()

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, svelte, sveltekit

im trying to add zoom and pan functionality to my chart but each time I zoom I get an error that says(also, this is what the chart looks like currently):
[image: this is the chart and the error]

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import * as d3 from "d3";

  let data = [
    {
      date: new Date("2023-01-01T18:00:00.000Z"),
      open: 1.06849,
      high: 1.06849,
      low: 1.06839,
      close: 1.06839,
    },
    {
      date: new Date("2023-01-01T19:00:00.000Z"),
      open: 1.06799,
      high: 1.06799,
      low: 1.06789,
      close: 1.06789,
    },
    {
      date: new Date("2023-01-01T20:00:00.000Z"),
      open: 1.06789,
      high: 1.06789,
      low: 1.06789,
      close: 1.06789,
    }...more and more data...
  ];

  let containerWidth = 800;
  let containerHeight = 800;
  let svg, xAxis, yAxis, gridX, gridY;

  // New variables for crosshair
  let crosshairX = -1;
  let crosshairY = -1;
  
  // Function to update crosshair position
  function updateCrosshair(event) {
    const [x, y] = d3.pointer(event);
    crosshairX = x;
    crosshairY = y;
  }

  // Function to reset crosshair position
  function resetCrosshair() {
    crosshairX = -1;
    crosshairY = -1;
  }

  $: xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map((d) => d.date))
    .range([0, containerWidth])
    .padding(0.2); // Adjust the padding as needed

  $: yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(data, (d) => +d.low), d3.max(data, (d) => +d.high)])
    .range([containerHeight, 0]);

  $: {
    d3.select(yAxis).call(d3.axisRight(yScale).tickFormat(d => {
              if (isNaN(d)) return "";
              return `${d.toFixed(5)}`;
          }));
    
    d3.select(xAxis).call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
    
    // Adding grid lines
    d3.select(gridY)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(-containerWidth).tickFormat(''));

    d3.select(gridX)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(containerHeight).tickFormat(''));
    
    d3.select(svg)
      .on("mousemove", updateCrosshair)
      .on("mouseleave", resetCrosshair);
  }

  // Function to handle zoom events
  function zoomed(event) {
    const zoomTransform = event.transform;
    const newXScale = zoomTransform.rescaleX(xScale);
    xScale = newXScale;
  }

  onMount(() => {
    // Your existing code for rendering the initial chart

    const zoomBehavior = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoomed);

    d3.select(svg)
      .call(zoomBehavior);
  });
</script>

<div class="main-chart-div">
  <div class="chart-and-price-div-group">
    <div
    class="chart"
    bind:clientHeight={containerHeight}
    bind:clientWidth={containerWidth}
  >
  <svg bind:this={svg} width="100%" height="100%">
    <g bind:this={gridX} class="grid-x" />
    <g bind:this={gridY} class="grid-y" />

    <!-- New code for crosshair lines -->
    {#if xScale && yScale && crosshairX >= 0 && crosshairY >= 0}
      <line
        x1={crosshairX}
        y1={0}
        x2={crosshairX}
        y2={containerHeight}
        class="crosshair-line"
      />
      <line
        x1={0}
        y1={crosshairY}
        x2={containerWidth}
        y2={crosshairY}
        class="crosshair-line"
      />
    {/if}
    
    {#if xScale && yScale}
      {#each data as d (d.date)}
        <line
          class="candlestick-line"
          x1={xScale(d.date) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}
          y1={yScale(d.high)}
          x2={xScale(d.date) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}
          y2={yScale(d.low)}
          stroke={d.close > d.open ? 'green' : 'red'}
        />
        <rect
          class="candlestick-rect"
          x={xScale(d.date)}
          y={d.close > d.open ? yScale(d.close) : yScale(d.open)}
          width={xScale.bandwidth()}
          height={Math.abs(yScale(d.open) - yScale(d.close))}
          fill={d.close > d.open ? 'green' : 'red'}
        />
      {/each}
    {/if}
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pricetab">
    <svg bind:this={yAxis}></svg>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timescale">
    <svg bind:this={xAxis}></svg>
  </div>
</div>


<style>
  .chart {
    width: 95%;
    height: 95vh;
    display: flex;
  }

  .chart-and-price-div-group {
    display: flex;
  }

  .pricetab {
    width: 5%;
    height: 95vh;
  }

  .pricetab svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95vh;
  }

  .timescale svg {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .candlestick-rect {
    shape-rendering: crispedges;
  }

  .candlestick-line {
    shape-rendering: crispedges;
  }

  .crosshair-line {
    stroke: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    stroke-dasharray: 5;
    shape-rendering: crispedges;
    stroke: 1px;
  }
</style>
```

ive tried zooming with rescaleX and it didnt work, i tried zooming with a  tag and it didnt work, i dont really know what to do anymore so i decided to give it to geniuses here on stackoverflow